# How to store bikes inside a house or unit with limited internal space?

Tags: storage

Between my girlfriend and myself, we have 5 bikes of which 3 would ideally be stored inside (the two road bikes and my duallie). However, my house is a relatively small terrace house which doesn't have huge spare rooms on the ground floor for bike storage.

What is the best storage solution you've seen for keeping the bikes inside that:

- Is compact and keeps the bikes relatively out of the way,
- Allows the bikes to be easily accessed for going on rides,
- Preferrably doesn't involve permanent fixtures on the wall, and
- Looks good?

Answer (score 7):

Friends of mine use a [Two-Bike Gravity Stand](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000ACAM38), and are really happy with it.  It doesn't require any modifications to your apartment, and does a pretty good job at keeping the bikes out of the way.  For myself, I installed a [pulley system](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001ENZFGQ), but that does involve drilling in the ceiling.

Comment: +1  I have two of these and they work great.  For safety there is a strap at the top of the stand that should be screwed into the wall to prevent the stand from tipping.

Comment: I like the look of that stand, I think that could be pretty close to what we want.

Comment: @deemar -I'd like to add, don't skimp on a cheap gravity stand. Spend a little extra to get a good one. (I learned this the hard way, my last stand required replacing several of the arms when the tension screws stripped during normal use, and and the new parts stripped just as badly.

Answer (score 4):

As I [posted](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/diy-wooden-bike-rack-looking-for-plans/1229#1229) on [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/diy-wooden-bike-rack-looking-for-plans/) question, my roomy and I have a pretty similar problem.  Our solution does require poking holes in the wall (8 I believe for our bikes) with drywall screws, but this is easily fixed with some white wood putty (from Home Depot or similar) when you're ready to move out.  Because we both ride year-round (including snow and rain days), we also lined the wall and floor with plastic to keep the dripping encased.  We now have 6 bikes (5 on the wall and a big-dummy under the breakfast bar), and have no indications of any problems after about a year.

[image]

It is basically a 2x4 screwed to the wall, with [hooks](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xr5/R-202305571/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) placed into it at a 45 degree angle.  Basically the wheel at the top is in contact with both the hook and the wall, and the bottom wheel is touching the wall.  Alternating hanging the bikes by the front and rear wheel means you can put the hooks closer together, and put more in the same space.  It is a very strong design, able to hold a couple of 40+ lbs bikes ([Pugsley](http://surlybikes.com/bikes/pugsley_complete/)) and 3 other bikes.

The size of hooks may vary.  For example, I have a large one for my [Pugsley](http://surlybikes.com/bikes/pugsley_complete/):

[image]

The plastic we used is also very cheap.  I think it was ~15$ for 100 feet of the stuff.  We plan to replace the plastic once it gets dirty, and I estimate the sheet we have will last 4-5 years.  We also used patches of duck-tape where the tires hit the plastic in order to prevent the tires from wearing through too quickly (especially important for the bikes with studded tires).

The most expensive part of the build was the hooks, the most expensive of which were ~15$ (going from memory).  I'd estimate the whole build can be done for ~100$ for 5 bikes.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable solution, but I think the bikes may project into the room space a bit much, and I don't really want to be drilling holes in my wall. This storage is for the "pretty" bikes in my collection (the road bikes), not the rough and tumble commuting bikes (which live out the back ready for instant action)

Comment: The original question called for not modifying the walls. (Hence my downvote.)

Comment: Awesome solution!  Very impressed.  I am definatly going to implement at my next apartment.

Comment: @Jack M., I HAVE to ask: what is the bike on the right?! :)

Comment: @joshmax *That* is a [Surly Big Dummy](http://surlybikes.com/bikes/big_dummy).  It's only up there for the photo.  =-]

Comment: @Jack M. - **THAT** is awesome.